# Parsing JSON using a conditional

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to pull information from an API but only use what I need. In this case, I need to pull the "id" and "location id" if the "site id" equals a pre-defined variable.

```
response = {
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 92,
      "site": {
        "id": 1,
      },
      "location": {
        "id": 2,
      },
    },
    {
      "id": 196,
      "site": {
        "id": 2,
      },
      "location": {
        "id": 8,
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For example, `if site == 2` then get the `id` 196, then the `location` `id` of 8, completely ignoring the first set of data.
I assume that I could do `payload["results"][1]["id"]` to get the ID from the second set of data, but what if it I don't know which set I need it from?

Comment: Where is the JSON in your question? That looks like Python code for a data structure that is the result of successfully parsing a JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you can iterate through the dictionary:

```py
for result in payload["results"]:
    if result["site"]["id"] == 2:
        result_id = (result["id"])
        location_id = result["location"]["id"]
        return result_id, location_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
results = response['results']
result_id = [r['id'] for r in results if r['site']['id'] == 2]
```

Output: `[196]`

If you are sure that the site id is unique or you only want to find the first occurence, then I would suggest to  to use a `break` (or `return` if in a function) to prevent unnecessary iterations.